# How to fix a button with javascript function in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get all title out of body text.
I created a button and linked my function to it.
However, when I click on it, it disappears and I want it to stay in the same place because I will add other buttons with other functions.
Do you know any idea how I could keep it always in there?
I tryed to use fixed position but soon realised that it just fixes the button on top if I scroll down for example.
Also, when I get the titles my text is in different shrift, I just wonder why is that?
Your guidance will be appreciated.
This is what I have at the moment:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
            #navigation li{
                display:inline;
                postion:absolute;
            }
            #navigation a{
                padding:2px 2px;
                background-color:#09F;
                color:#FFFFFF;
            }
            #navigation a:hover{
                background-color:#F90;
                color:#666;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="navigation">
            <a href="#"><input type=button onclick="myFunction()">
        </div>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p id="demo">
                <pre> 
                    <b>This is one title</b>

                    I'm writing here
                    the text that I 
                    don't need to get.

                    <b>Other title</b>

                    And so we'll test
                    whether this thing works.
                </p>
            </pre>
        </div>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var text = document.body.innerText;
                var titles =text.match(/^\n(.+?)\n\n/mg);
                for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                    document.write(titles[i] + "<br />" + "<br />");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use absolute positioning for the button

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You should not have any HTML elements before the body tag. Validate your HTML then re-approach your problem.

Comment: Just remove the `<a href="#">` in front of your button. Because you never close it, the whole page becomes one big link. And as @captainrad said, validate your HTML because there is a lot wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestions on how I should work with HTML, I'm just learning so you really helped me a lot, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here you go.](http://jsfiddle.net/61fdqydt/) I have fixed the HTML, made it more semantic (by removing the onclick from the HTML), and made the algorithm simpler by using `document.getElementsByTagName()`.

 New code:

```
var r = document.getElementById('results');

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = myFunction;

function myFunction() {
    var titles = document.getElementsByTagName('b');
    for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
      r.innerHTML += titles[i].innerHTML + "<br />" + "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked like wonder!
Thank you for your help, now I will know how to arrange my HTML :)

Comment: I really would, but I still don't have the reputation to do so. I will do it when my reputation gets higher : )

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have an opening `<a>` tag but not a closing one. That makes your whole website a link. But apart from that you had a lot of invalid HTML. Closing tags that were mixed up and HTML between `</head>` and `<body>`.

Your HTML should look like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        #navigation li{
            display:inline;
            postion:absolute;
        }
        #navigation a{
            padding:2px 2px;
            background-color:#09F;
            color:#FFFFFF;
        }
        #navigation a:hover{
            background-color:#F90;
            color:#666;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navigation">
        <input type=button onclick="myFunction()" />
    </div> 
    <div>
        <p id="demo">
            <pre> 
                <b>This is one title</b>

                I'm writing here
                the text that I 
                don't need to get.

                <b>Other title</b>

                And so we'll test
                whether this thing works.
            </pre>
        </p>
    </div>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var text = document.body.innerText;
            var titles =text.match(/^\n(.+?)\n\n/mg);
            for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                document.write(titles[i] + "<br />" + "<br />");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```